# Java Spring Boot Testing with MySQL Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing, database-testing

My tests for this CRUD operation in Spring Boot continue to fail where I get "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No Value Present" I understand that testCreateDemographic is creating a record, however, testFindDemographicsById is not able to find the newly created record because it is using "1L" in findById(1L) to find a record. How do I get the correct new related record Id to place in findById() argument?

```
package com.lizardkinghotel.demographic;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.lizardkinghotel.demographic.entities.DemographicEntity;
import com.lizardkinghotel.demographic.repos.DemographicRepository;

@SpringBootTest 
class DemographicAppApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private DemographicRepository demoRepo;

    @Test
    public void testCreateDemographic() {

        DemographicEntity demoEntity = new DemographicEntity();

        //demoEntity.setId(1L);
        demoEntity.setAge("39–47");
        demoEntity.setChildren(2);
        demoEntity.setCity("san jose");;
        demoEntity.setCountry("costa rica");
        demoEntity.setEducation("bacherlors degree");
        demoEntity.setEmail("test@test.com");
        demoEntity.setEmployment("yes");
        demoEntity.setGender("male");       
        demoEntity.setGuestAmount(2);
        demoEntity.setHearAbout("google search");

        demoRepo.save(demoEntity);      

    }


    @Test
    public void testFindDemographicsById() {

        DemographicEntity demoEntity = demoRepo.findById(1L).get();     

    }

    //testing updating a record
    @Test
    public void testUpdateDemo() {

        DemographicEntity demoEntity = demoRepo.findById(1L).get();     
        demoRepo.save(demoEntity);

    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteDemo() {

        DemographicEntity demoEntity = demoRepo.findById(1L).get();     
        demoRepo.delete(demoEntity);

    }   


}
```

Below is my error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at com.lizardkinghotel.demographic.DemographicAppApplicationTests.testFindDemographicsById(DemographicAppApplicationTests.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: I see you have commented out the setId method before saving the entity in DB. Is the Id field some sort of autogenerated sequence number?

Comment: @SandeepLakdawala yes it is autogenerated.

Comment: @coder3 the test cases run in a random sequence. Are you sure that the save method - testCreateDemographic is getting executed before the get method - testFindDemographicsById?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit test should not depend on the other. Which means change your findById test to something like this:

```
@Test
public void testFindDemographicsById() {

    DemographicEntity demoEntity = new DemographicEntity();
    demoEntity.setAge("39–47");
    demoEntity.setChildren(2);
    demoEntity.setCity("san jose");;
    demoEntity.setCountry("costa rica");
    demoEntity.setEducation("bacherlors degree");
    demoEntity.setEmail("test@test.com");
    demoEntity.setEmployment("yes");
    demoEntity.setGender("male");       
    demoEntity.setGuestAmount(2);
    demoEntity.setHearAbout("google search");

    DemographicEntity saved = demoRepo.save(demoEntity); 

    DemographicEntity demoEntity = demoRepo.findById(saved.getId()).get();     

}
```